# ウェブに関しての入門的なプログラミング

Tags: linux

linuxでプログラミングがしたいのですが、
手始めにウェブページをダウンロードしてきてhtmlのソースが端末画面に表示されるような入門的なプログラムが書きたいのですがどうしたらいいかわかりません
なにか参考にできる書籍やページはありませんか

言語はまだ決まっていませんがCが少し扱える程度です。
より簡単にできる言語やそれ向きの言語があるのであればそちらを勉強します。

Comment: この質問を消したいです。が、削除ボタンも通報ボタンも言うことを聞きません。発見した人は通報してください。

Comment: 質問にクローズ票を投じます。オフトピックである理由: 質問の範囲が広すぎる、あるいは主観的な答しか集らない、などの問題があります。質問者ご本人もクローズをご希望のようです。

Comment: @mjy 質問者さんはクローズというか削除を望まれているようですが、そこまではしない方がいいでしょうか？

Comment: @unarist  「削除」を希望されている理由ですが、内容に著作権侵害があるような特別な事情は無さそうですし、やはり内容が Stack Overflow になじまないと思った、などではないかと推測します。それならば、質問者さんとしてもシステム上に用意されてるクローズでよさそうです。回答も付いている事ですし、どなたかが質問の改善にチャレンジする機会も一応あってよいかと思います。

Answer (score 1):

`Ruby`や`Python`それに最近だと`Nodejs`などが使いやすいんじゃないでしょうか。

Rubyであれば

#### yahoo_html_source.rb

```
require 'open-uri'
open('http://yahoo.co.jp').read
```

とファイルを作成して

```
ruby yahoo_html_source.rb
```

と実行すれば画面上にHTMLのソースが表示されます。

またlinux上でのプログラミングを行うのであれば`ls`や`cd`などの基本的なコマンドが必須になりますのでそちら関連の本も買うのをおすすめします。

Answer (score -5):

はじめまして、プロスタ編集部です。

質問者様のlinux学習にお役に立ちたいと思い、おすすめのチュートリアルを紹介します。
(参考サイト：【Linuxの本・参考書の評判】[http://programming-study.com/language/linux-books/])

下記の5冊の書籍がおすすめです。ぜひご参考にしてみてください。

1.独習Linux 第2版
2.ふつうのLinuxプログラミング Linuxの仕組みから学べるgccプログラミングの王道
3.新しいLinuxの教科書
4.プロのための Linuxシステム構築・運用技術 (Software Design plus)
5.図解でわかる Linuxサーバ構築・設定のすべて